# How best to deal with template headers in clion for code generation to work?

Tags: c++, templates, cmake, clion

CLion does not offer code generation for functions in template classes in header files that are not source files for the executable or there is no corresponding source file.

CLion will also offer up warnings when it can't resolve a symbol (that would lead to a compilation error) in cases where code generation also works.

So my question is, what are the ideal ways of working with template header files in CLion?

Example where code generation does not work:

```
// foo.hpp
template<typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  void Bar();
};

# CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(exe not_foo.hpp)
```

Example where code generation does work:

```
// foo.hpp
#pragma once
template<typename T>
class Foo {
 public:
  void Bar();
};

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
// EOF

# CMakeLists.txt
add_executable(exe foo.cpp)
```

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but there is no such thing as code generation for templates until you instantiate them. How are you instantiating your templates? What do you mean by "it's not working"? Do you have errors during generation/compilation?

Comment: I'm talking about the Generate function in CLion.

When you right click Bar in the first example the *Generate* function is greyed out.

The *Generate* feature in CLion generates the function definition.